# Out of range: FIFOQueue '_1_create_inputs/batch/fifo_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 2, current size 1)

Tags: python, tensorflow

I get the following error when attempting to train. Any help is much appreciated!

> Out of range: FIFOQueue '_1_create_inputs/batch/fifo_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 2, current size 1)

```
2017-05-11 09:20:07.383254: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:1152] Unknown: NewRandomAccessFile failed to Create/Open: E:\Yared\tensorflow-deeplab-resnet-master\pro : Access is denied.
; Input/output error
2017-05-11 09:20:07.383254: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:1152] Unknown: NewRandomAccessFile failed to Create/Open: E:\Yared\tensorflow-deeplab-resnet-master\pro : Access is denied.
; Input/output error

The checkpoint has been created.
step 0   loss = 11.668, (13.483 sec/step)
step 1   loss = 10.058, (0.697 sec/step)
2017-05-11 09:20:21.200215: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:1152] Out of range: FIFOQueue '_1_create_inputs/batch/fifo_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 2, current size 1)
         [[Node: create_inputs/batch = QueueDequeueManyV2[component_types=[DT_FLOAT, DT_UINT8], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](create_inputs/batch/fifo_queue, create_inputs/batch/n)]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\admin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1039, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "C:\Users\admin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1021, in _run_fn
    status, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\admin\Anaconda3\lib\contextlib.py", line 66, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Users\admin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py", line 466, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
    pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.OutOfRangeError: FIFOQueue '_1_create_inputs/batch/fifo_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 2, current size 1)
         [[Node: create_inputs/batch = QueueDequeueManyV2[component_types=[DT_FLOAT, DT_UINT8], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](create_inputs/batch/fifo_queue, create_inputs/batch/n)]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 253, in <module>
    main()
  File "train.py", line 246, in main
    loss_value, _ = sess.run([reduced_loss, train_op], feed_dict=feed_dict)
  File "C:\Users\admin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 778, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "C:\Users\admin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 982, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\admin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1032, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\admin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1052, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.OutOfRangeError: FIFOQueue '_1_create_inputs/batch/fifo_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 2, current size 1)
         [[Node: create_inputs/batch = QueueDequeueManyV2[component_types=[DT_FLOAT, DT_UINT8], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](create_inputs/batch/fifo_queue, create_inputs/batch/n)]]

Caused by op 'create_inputs/batch', defined at:
  File "train.py", line 253, in <module>
    main()
  File "train.py", line 141, in main
    image_batch, label_batch = reader.dequeue(args.batch_size)
  File "E:\Yared\tensorflow-deeplab-resnet-master\deeplab_resnet\image_reader.py", line 179, in dequeue
    num_elements)
  File "C:\Users\admin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\input.py", line 917, in batch
    name=name)
  File "C:\Users\admin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\input.py", line 712, in _batch
    dequeued = queue.dequeue_many(batch_size, name=name)
  File "C:\Users\admin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\data_flow_ops.py", line 458, in dequeue_many
    self._queue_ref, n=n, component_types=self._dtypes, name=name)
  File "C:\Users\admin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_data_flow_ops.py", line 1328, in _queue_dequeue_many_v2
    timeout_ms=timeout_ms, name=name)
  File "C:\Users\admin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 768, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Users\admin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 2336, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Users\admin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1228, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()

OutOfRangeError (see above for traceback): FIFOQueue '_1_create_inputs/batch/fifo_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 2, current size 1)
         [[Node: create_inputs/batch = QueueDequeueManyV2[component_types=[DT_FLOAT, DT_UINT8], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](create_inputs/batch/fifo_queue, create_inputs/batch/n)]]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, queue is exhausted because it couldn't load files (restricted access)

First line in your error :

```
2017-05-11 09:20:07.383254: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:1152] Unknown: NewRandomAccessFile failed to Create/Open: E:\Yared\tensorflow-deeplab-resnet-master\pro : Access is denied.
; Input/output error
```

Do you have access to E:\Yared\tensorflow-deeplab-resnet-master\pro ??

Also, I am not sure how did it run for two steps.

Comment: @Utopia, Did you figure out the mistake ??